# Can't get native resolution (1440p and 144 Hz) on Ubuntu 20.04 with Nvidia Card

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 20.04, display-resolution

Here is my problem, which I can't solve.

I bought a new 27" display (Samsung) with a native resolution of **2560 x 1440p** for a frequency of **144 Hz**. The screen works perfectly as a dual screen on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop (Intel integrated chipset) and on a DELL Win10 laptop.

Problem, I bought it for my tower which is equipped with a **Nvidia GT 610** Fanless graphics card. I suspect this graphics card because neither the screen nor the HDMI cable are involved (cable sold with the screen).

If I boot on my USB key, I end up with a 120Hz frequency that overwrites the text in height, if I switch back to 60Hz and 1920x1080 resolution, I find a nearly normal display.
It's the same problem if I boot on my Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome), neither with the Nvidia 390 driver nor with Nouveau, I have no access to the native resolution of the screen, I'm only in Full-Hd (60Hz).

I made some tests here :

```
bristow@Desktop:~$ xrandr --newmode $(gtf 2560 1440 144 | sed -ne 's/"//g;s/ Modeline //p')
bristow@Desktop:~$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1440_144.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

I have this error and therefore cannot activate the resolution. If an expert could get through?

If it's my graphics card, what can I buy to make sure I have the right resolution with 144Hz frequency (fanless on the other hand)?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that error message simply means the mode is already added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, it was my video card.

I bought a Nvidia GT1030 with HDMI et DP ports and i have good resolution and refresh rate \o/

Comment: EXCELLENT!!!! I could not get my 1440p (60hz) monitor to show at native resolution on a 610 either. I've tried everything and now I know that the card is the culprit. Thank you so much for setting my mind at ease.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem, tried to fix it for an hour. Dell Optiplex 790 i7 with AMD RX 550 GPU on Kubuntu.

I needed to reset my CMOS for something else, and after I pulled the battery out for 10 mins and booted up I had a crisp clear 1440p display! (Not 1080) Hope this might help someone!

https://ibb.co/g3MbFVG